# Number of Diagonals in Regular Polygon Makes me Question my Sanity

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, solution-verification

I wanted to find the number of diagonals to a dodecagon. I know the standard way is to use the formula $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$, but I always forget the formula, so I used combinatorics. I tackled the problem from the perspective of drawing lines starting from a point. Since two adjacent points cannot create a diagonal, you have nine other dots to select from for where to draw the diagonal. Because the starting dot does not matter, this leaves us with $\binom{11}{9}$ possible drawings. Because it is possible to choose to draw to the same dot, we must exclude that possibility. Thus, there are $\binom{11}{9}-1$ diagonals to the dodecagon.

If I were to generalize this to some regular $n$-gon, then there are $\binom{n-1}{n-3}-1$ diagonals. **Can this reasoning apply to any regular $n$-gon?** I'd rather not memorize that formula, and this method seems to work (I tried it with $n = 6, 7, 12$).

Comment: Yes your method is correct.

Comment: But also a simple reasoning which helps remember $n(n-3)/2$ directly: There are $n(n-3)$ ways to select one vertex, then a second vertex not equal to or next to the first. This determines all the diagonals, but in exactly $2$ ways for each diagonal, with one end or the other as the first vertex selected.

Comment: Or you can also use ${n \choose 2}-n$, since ${n \choose 2}$ is the number of line segments between two vertices, including the $n$ edges.

Comment: I don't really understand how you got to ${{11} \choose 9}$ though.

Comment: @aschepler If I am a diagonal on a dodecagon, I will choose to go to any dot that is not myself, so I am choosing from 11 dots. I also choose not to go to any of the adjacent dots. I choose to exclude the two adjacent dots, so there are $\binom{11}{9}$ choices.

Comment: Another way to handle the problem is to observe that there are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to connect any two of the vertices of a polygon with $n$ sides, but $n$ of these are sides of the polygon, so there are $\binom{n}{2} - n$ diagonals.  You can simplify that expression to obtain the formula $\frac{n(n - 3)}{2}$.

Comment: ${{11}\choose 9}$ is the number of ways to choose $9$ different things out of a total of $11$. You're not choosing $9$ different things. On a hexagon, what would the ${5 \choose 3}=10$ things be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both formulae are correct.

$$ \begin{align*} {{n-1}\choose{n-3}} - 1 &= \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-3)!\cdot 2!} - 1 \\
&= \frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots 2 \cdot 1}{2(n-3)(n-4)\cdots 2 \cdot 1} - 1 \\
&= \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2} - 1 \\
&= \frac{n^2-3n+2}{2} - \frac{2}{2} \\
&= \frac{n(n-3)}{2}
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Thank you! I was worried the algebraic simplification would be more complicated, but it turned out to be more simple than I thought.